# how to upload videos from my server to vimeo server using php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, vimeo

Currently i am using   https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php .here search is working perfect. client_id, token access all are perfect. but i have a problem with video upload to vimeo server. i found some informations from [vimeo developer API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#simple-http-post-uploading)
here they are asking to generate an UPLOAD TICKET using HTTP POST to a specified url(https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos). what can i do for this http post to that url? is it using php curl or using ajax post?